# Spring security control access - same page but with different parameter id

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Suppose I have two employees with different information, the url looks likes

```
http://localhost:8080/springtest/{empId}
```

and using empInfo.jsp page.

When Employee with id 1 logging to the system, he can access http://localhost:8080/springtest/1, but he cannot access http://localhost:8080/springtest/2, and vice versa

What should be the best practice to achieve this with Spring? The role for both Employee will be "User"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security provides you with a method for retrieving the principal i.e. the user who is currently logged in.

```
User principal = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

now, you can do all your security checks based on those attributes that characterize a user with respect to one another. For example a userid, or whatever.

in your case you could do the following

```
    if(principal.getId()==empId)
        //PROCEED...
    else
        //STOP! GO TO 403!
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a groups with roles. Than add users to different groups with different roles.

roles : R
groups : G 
users : U
m2m : many to many relationship

R m2m G

G m2m U

Basically, add one more layer after roles

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add some security controls in your java controller, I give you an algorithmic example :

```
If the current user id equals to the parameter id 
    then redirect to the good page
    else redirect to 403 Forbidden page or Another error page
```